# How to remove all list partition without dropping table structure

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

I have around 600 tables. How to drop list partition from oracle table without dropping table structure.

Comment: [See the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/maintenance-partition-tables-indexes.html#GUID-BAFFE31C-07A2-4ED6-BDCF-8ECB79D7FE7D)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP PARTITION partition_name;
```

or
DELETE FROM table PARTITION(partition_name);

I understand that you want to drop them not truncate, otherwise, you must replace DROP by TRUNCATE.

If you want to remove all partitions automatically.
Create a CURSOR, sharing information of ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS.
After the CURSOR create a LOOP to move into the table partitions.

If that can helps you, ask me and I give you more details.